# {plain}password in Database and login error

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, login-script

I am coding a login panel to access to an Administration Panel.
The data (username and passw) are stored in a MySQL Database (type: InnoDB).
Looking in the tables the passwords are stored as plain and in the field password I have:
{plain}password.

Adapting a code that I already have, I have some problems because that {plain} thing is confusing me a bit.

My old code is:

```
// Construct SQL statement for query & execute 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . md5($password) . "'"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

So if I replace the "{plain}password" from the field in the database with an MD5 password, the code works great, but if I modify my code to the following one:

```
// Construct SQL statement for query & execute 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I can't login because the password is wrong!

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to concatenate '{plain}' to the password?

Comment: Please see http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: See also: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: great webcomic, but don't get me wrong the code you read was only a part. I know how to work buddy.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is the prefix "{plain}" in front of the real password, you have to adjust your query to include that prefix.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = '" . $username . "' AND password = '{plain}" . $password . "'"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error());
```

Also note that you should change `mysql_error()` in the `die()` command to use `mysqli` functions as well (so use `$mysqli->error`).

PS: You should have a look at how to store password nowadays. Storing them in plain text is not secure by any means.

**EDIT**

Mentioning the comment by @BrianRasmussen here as well:
Make sure `$username` and `$password` have been sanitzed before being used directly (using string concat) in a query! Otherwise your code is open to SQL injections of all sorts.

Comment: Neither is constructing queries directly from user input.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Where do you see construction of a query directly from user input? `$username` and `$password` might (and should have) be sanitized before.

Comment: @Sirko: thank you for your kind answer, unfortunately I was only asking if that {plain} thing was something special or particular. thank you also for the advise about how to store the password in the Database, but unfortunately I am working on someone else code and I can't modify anything.
I know that it is a bad thing store plain password in the DB, but i am a Junior coder and can't modify what Senior did :(

About the SQL injection, my previous code was only to understand where was the problem, if it was my problem or old code problem. But thank you anyway

Comment: @Mark Maybe you could point him towards recent password leaks and the blog entries about their decoding. Could make you look like the senior coder instead ,-)

Comment: @Sirko: I know, I already did and the answer was, just code and leave old things as they are. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure what `{plain}` means, I guess it indicates that the password is in plain text - and this string is actually present.  Hence, your second SQL should include it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "' AND password = '{plain}" . mysql_real_escape_string($password) . "'";
```

Note that I'm not starting the discussion about storing admin passwords in plain text, purely answering a technical question.  However I **must** say that storing plain text passwords is a VERY bad idea.

Also note that I added `mysql_real_escape_string` to sanitise your input.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, unfortunately I was only asking if that {plain} thing was something special or particular. thank you also for the advise about how to store the password in the Database, but unfortunately I am working on someone else code and I can't modify anything.
I know that it is a bad thing store plain password in the DB, but i am a Junior coder and can't modify what Senior did :(